# Can I see which app modified service settings in Windows?

Tags: windows-7, services

Background: something turned off a bunch of services, and the network connection failed when I eventually rebooted the computer.  I want to know why this happened =)

I looked through the system log: nothing was happening at that moment except for the network services startup being switched to "Disabled". The entries themselves do not list the event cause.

So can I see what turned those services' startup off? And what could that be? I thought only privileged apps / users could do that.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit